# google script loops executed only once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I pass data from one function to another in which I have loop. Loop is executed only once and not as much as the data.length. Please help.

```
function first(){
  //start code...

  var symbol = filetext.substr(filetext.search("Title:"));
  symbol = symbol.split(' ');
  symbol = symbol[1]; //someText

  if(symbol == 'someText') {
    second(symbol);
  }
}

function second(symbol){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('tests');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ //data has at least 10 rows
    var row = data[i];
    var type = row[0];
    var status = row[3];
    Logger.log(type) //shows only first row not all;
    if (type == symbol) {
        //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried additional logging to troubleshoot? Perhaps `Logger.log(data.length)` and `Logger.log(data)` before the loop begins.

Comment: Show code in `//do something`

Comment: may be something error in your 'if (type == symbol) { }'

Comment: Please display more of your code or share a sanitised copy of your sheet as there is not enough information here to be able to help.

Comment: I have a 'break' inside my loop. Question, obviously, to close